# Display number as float using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c#-4.0, input, angularjs-directive

I have a requirement to have a text box to enter amount. We should restrict entering special characters and decimal point.i have done the restriction part using custom filters. Have a requirement on same text box to display the entered number automatically to float with two decimal point. When I added filter

Can anyone suggest me to achieve this using angularjs.

Here is the input text

Comment: It'd be better if you could've posted the code snippet which would help to understand better.

Comment: added code as well

Comment: <input type="text" name="amount"  ng-model="vm.model.amount|currency:''"  validate-mynumber  required />

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a directive to restrict an input to float:

```
.directive('floatOnly', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue === undefined) return '';

        // Remove forbidden characters
        cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(',', '.') // change commas to dots
          .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') // keep numbers and dots
          .replace(/\./, "x") // change the first dot in X
          .replace(/\./g, "") // remove all dots
          .replace(/x/, "."); // change X to dot
        if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return cleanInputValue;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can use it as following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myFloat" float-only/>
```

## Test snippet:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]).directive('floatOnly', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue === undefined) return '';

        // Remove forbidden characters
        cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(',', '.') // change commas to dots
          .replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') // keep numbers and dots
          .replace(/\./, "x") // change the first dot in X
          .replace(/\./g, "") // remove all dots
          .replace(/x/, "."); // change X to dot
        if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return cleanInputValue;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Float only: <input type="text" ng-model="myFloat" float-only/>
  </div>
</div>
```

## [Test it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvttncdv/1/)

Play with it trying to type anything on the input

Comment: My requirement is not to allow decimal point through keyboard and automatically format the number to two decimal point (.00)